# Send SMS to multiple phone number when messenger is set as default sms app in android

Tags: android, messenger, android-sms

I have implemented the ability to send message in my app and it is working well. But if the user is using another sms app like `messenger` as their default sms app then, I can't send message to multiple recipients. 
If multiple phone number is selected, only one of them get the message in most cases the last phone number.

**NOTE:** I'm using an `implicit intent` to send the message and it can send to multiple recipients on stock sms app.

Any help will ve greatly appreciated.

This is what I have as requested

```
Intent intent;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");

        String defaultSmsPackage = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(getActivity());
        if (defaultSmsPackage != null) {
            intent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackage);
        }
    } else {
        Uri numbersUri = Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumbers);
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, numbersUri);
        intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    }

    intent.putExtra("address", phoneNumbers);
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Please add your implementation.

Comment: Post some code ,it sounds ambiguity..

Comment: Confused with Problem Statement & NOTE.

Comment: Do you have any implementation that you have tried ?

Comment: Code added, you can check it out